# Where should a compiled script be placed in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, openpgp.js

I am trying to include client side library (`OpenPGP.js`) in my react application to allow multiple react components to interact with OpenPGP.js via utility functions. Where should I place the script tag `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openpgp/2.5.11/openpgp.js"></script>`? Also, where should I write my utility functions (as shown in https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs#examples) such that they are accessible to all my components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you consider using `npm install --save openpgp`?. If you are you using npm for your project?

Then you can import it in any component like below

```
import openpgp from 'openpgp';
```

and use it like below.

```
openpgp.initWorker({ path:'openpgp.worker.js' });
```

Comment: These util functions don't have UI as they take data from a calling function and return manipulated data. How would that work if there are multiple components calling these util functions? (From what I can understand, if I implement the code that you suggested at component level, I will have hundreds of copy of the same code if I create hundreds of component, right?)

Comment: No if you use the way i told, you will have only one copy and references you use at 100 palces :)

Comment: Should I write the util functions as part of Actions?

Comment: How is your project scaffolded? Are you using some build tool like webpack or grunt?

Comment: I am using webpack and I have directories for actions, components, and reducers under src directory. The project was created with help of create_react_app.

Comment: There is no need to write any util function as far as you are using openpgp object imported from 'openpgp'. For extra processing yes actions is the right place to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156258/discussion-between-rahil-parikh-and-ranjeet-gautam).